# Difference between Blue scores and Baseline Bleu score for the model

Tags: evaluation, microsoft-translator

I created a model using my `dataset` and got a Bleu score/baseline Bleu score, what is the difference between them?

How is the baseline computed?

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/what-is-bleu-score) does not describe the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The baseline bleu score is the bleu score generated by sending your test data to our general MS models for translation.  The difference between the baseline bleu and the non-baseline bleu is the improvement you will see if you use the Custom Translator model.